# Monitor applications' network traffic

Tags: linux, monitoring, traffic

I just run iptraf to see many UDP traffic on eth0. How can I check which applications do the most network traffic? (Like iptraf but at application level)

Comment: what O/S?  Guess Linux if your IFs are called ethX

Comment: Linux (ArchLinux)

Answer (score 5):

[nethogs](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score -1):

You could try Network Probe at

http://www.objectplanet.com/probe/